# R function: strange behaviour with plot inside function

Tags: r

I am getting strange behaviour when putting plots inside functions (using ggplot with R from 'R Studio' 0.99.484).

I don't understand why locally scoped variables cannot be used to generate the plot. Perhaps you can enlighten me, and tell me of the right way to do it.

Here is a small code snippet reproducing my troubles:

```
# This works:
x1 <- seq(0,90,10)
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=x1,y=x1))

# This yields error below:
f1 <- function() {
  x2 <- seq(0,90,10)
  ret <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=x2,y=x2))
  return(ret)
}
f1()

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x2' not found

# This fixes the error: but why myX needs to be global?
f1 <- function() {
  myX <<- seq(0,90,10) 
  ret <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=myX,y=myX))
  return(ret)
}
f1()

# This yields error below:
f2 <- function(d) {
  ret <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=d,y=d))
  return(ret)
}
f2(x1)

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'd' not found

# This fixes the error making all global: is this the right way to do it?
f2 <- function(d) {
  myX <<- d
  ret <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=myX,y=myX))
  return(ret)
}
f2(x1)
```

Comment: You should be using data frames really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, the problem is that you're declaring a varible `x2`inside a function and that variable is local to that function. That's why you get the error: *object 'x2' not found*

If you want to make that variable accesible outside the function you can use the operator `<<-` instead of `<-`, or the function `assign` to assign it explicitly to the global environment. O you can just make the assignment outside the function.

```
# Option 1: <<-
    f1 <- function() {
      x2 <<- seq(0,90,10)
      ret <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=x2,y=x2))
      return(ret)
    }
    f1()

# Option2: assign  
    f1 <- function() {
      assign(x = "x2", value = seq(0,90,10), envir=.GlobalEnv)
      ret <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=x2,y=x2))
      return(ret)
    }
    f1()
# Option 3: assignment outside the function
x2 <- seq(0,90,10)
f1 <- function() {
  ret <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=x2,y=x2))
  return(ret)
}
f1()
```

Expanding the answer. The reason is because there is a [bug in ggplot2](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/743):

> Expressions in aes() are evaluated in the global environment, but they
>   should be evaluated in the calling environment.

Another workaround is to use a data frame (we shouldn't use vectors). Because `aes` looks first in the data frame passed to ggplot and then in the global environment. With this code you won't get the error:

```
f1 <- function() {
  x1 <- data.frame(x1 = seq(0,90,10))
  ret <- ggplot(x1, aes(x = x1, y= x1)) + geom_line()
  return(ret)
}
f1()
```

Finally, it's important to remember that in ggplot2 the data must be an R data frame. Hadley Wickham explicitly said in *ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis*:

> The restriction on the data is simple: it must be a data frame. This
>   is restrictive, and unlike other graphics packages in R.

Comment: Ok thank you, I updated my question and geve you the answer, since now it works. I don't understand why ggplot cannot access the locally defined variable however, if you could elaborate... :)

Comment: @HugoZaragoza You're welcome. I expanded the answer. I hope it clarifies more the issue.